# how do I observe for changes on the root object of dstore?

Tags: dojo

My data store consists of an array of items, and I would like to be notified when an item is added or removed from the array.  How can i do this?  I tried to extract a property object on the entire data, but it was unsuccessful.

```
<script>

    require(
        [
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dstore/Memory',
        'dmodel/extensions/jsonSchema',
        'dmodel/validators/StringValidator',
        'dmodel/store/Validating',
        "dmodel/Model",
        "dojox/json/schema",
        "dojo/text!app/model/testing/baseSchema.json",
        ], 
    function (declare, Memory, jsonSchema, StringValidator, Validating, Model, DJS, mySchema) {


        var validatingMemory2 = (declare([Memory, Validating]))({
            Model: jsonSchema(
                {
                    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                    "title": "Form Elements",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "title": "Form Element",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "description": "identifier",
                                "type": "string"
                            },

                            "positionX": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },

                            "positionY": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "moduleType": {
                                "description": "type",
                                "type": "string"
                            }

                        },
                        "required": ["id"],
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }
                }

                ),

            idProperty: "id",

        });


        validatingMemory2.setData([{ "id": "one", "positionX": 100, "positionY": 200, "moduleType": "label" }]);
        console.log(validatingMemory2);

        //error: property is not a function
        var prpertyObject = validatingMemory2..property("items");

        //I want to be alerted here when the item is added
        validatingMemory2.addSync({ "id": "two", "positionX": 300, "positionY": 400, "moduleType": "label" }); 

        console.log(validatingMemory2);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Data Notifications in dstore.

You can  monitor data changes receiving notifications using listeners that can be registered through the `on()` method, with different forms of notifications designed by distinct event types: add, update, and delete.

Try using this in your code:

```
validatingMemory2 .on('delete, add, update', function(event){
    // execute when a change is made to your store
});
```

Additional information can be found here:

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/11/17/introducing-dstore/

http://dstorejs.io/tutorials/realtime_stores.html